# Inequality in a proof that every b-adic number is a Cauchy-Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, cauchy-sequences

I have troubles understanding a step in a proof.

Let $\pm\sum_{n=-k}^{\infty}a_nb^{-n}$ be a b-adic number with $a_n,b,k\in\mathbb{N}$, $b\ge 2$ and $0\leq a_n<b$. We want to prove that this number is a
Cauchy-Seqence. The prove given in my textbook now uses the partial-sums $x_n:=\sum_{v=-k}^{n}a_vb^{-v}$ and shows, that (x_n) is a Cauchy-Sequence. Given $\epsilon>0$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $b^{-N}<\epsilon$. Then we have for $n\ge m\ge N$ that

$$|x_n-x_m| =\sum_{v=m+1}^{n}a_vb^{-v}\leq \sum_{v=m+1}^{n}(b-1)b^{-v}$$

The proof continues but my problem is with the last step in the above equation.

I know and tried that $a_vb^{-v}\leq bb^{-v}$ for all $a_v$, $(b-1)b^{-v}=b^{1-v}-b^{-v}$ and $\sum_{v=m+1}^{n}(b-1)b^{-v}=b^{-m}-b^{-n}$. But all these don't let me understand this inequality. Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks in advance. Please let me know if additional context is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a_n,b\in\mathbb{N}$, the given condition $a_n<b$ implies
$$ a_n\le b-1$$
for all $n$.

In other words, the greatest integer that is less than an integer $b$ is $b-1$.

Comment: Sometimes, I am blind… Thx!

Comment: Me too. You are welcome.